# How to retrieve a process description and company name using a handle to it?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++

How can I retrieve a process description and company name using a handle to it.
I'm using Windows API function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version (and copyright) informations are stored in the file version info. You can obtain them using the [`GetFileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Version can be retrieved with a *simple* call to `GetFileVersionInfo` to fill the [`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure but copyright information (in your case *ProductName* and *CompanyName*) is stored in localized/localizable text fields. For an example look the [`VerQueryValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: This is only half the answer.  The other half is `GetModuleFileNameEx`, which gets you from process handle to filename of main executable.

Comment: Tnx @BenVoigt, I didn't understand he had trouble to find the handle itself!

Comment: @Adriano: He says he has a handle to the process.  You can't pass that directly to `GetFileVersionInfo`.

Answer (score -1):

Depending of the type and the amount of information you need and where your handle is getting from you can begin with [PROCESSENTRY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I't doesn't contain description or compony name.